# how to check if two rough word are the same in python

Tags: python, string, nlp

I have four strings:

```
A = "eat apple"
B = "eat apples"
C = "eats apple"
D = "eats apples"
```

The four strings mean the same thing but only have very little difference in the string construct.

Is there some python code can detect that those four string are the same or high similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Depending on your definition of same/different you can get a universe of answers.

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python string similarity", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: If you refer to semantic similarity I recommend SpaCy https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use fuzzywuzzy:You can install with

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy[speedup]
```

Code example:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


def fuzz_check(text_1, text_2):

    r = fuzz.ratio(text_1,text_2)

    pr = fuzz.partial_ratio(text_1,text_2)

    print(f'`{text_1}` and `{text_2}` has'
          f' ratio of {r} and partial ratio of {pr}' )

A = "eat apple"
B = "eat apples"
C = "eats apple"
D = "eats apples"

fuzz_check(A,B)
fuzz_check(A,C)
```

Here is a documentation https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/README.rst

Answer (score 1):

You can use WordNetLemmatizer from nlp library nltk.

Here is a good example on [geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-lemmatization-with-nltk/)

Comment: Tokenize the Sentence and use WordNetLemmatizer https://medium.com/@datamonsters/text-preprocessing-in-python-steps-tools-and-examples-bf025f872908